# Pandas, read_excel not including leading 0's into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My excel file looks like:

[image]

with the ID has a "General" format.

Now when I read this file in with pandas I am returning `13335`.

[image]

```
gco = (r"path")

gco = pd.read_excel(gco)
```

is there a way to preserve the leading 0's with python?

Comment: `pd.read_excel(gco, dtype={"Project ID": str})`

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the datatype as int, it will covert to int and remove the leading ZEROs.

pd.read_excel(gco,dtype={'Project ID':'int'})